# dynamically imported css file getting not getting deferred when using typescript

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have this code in a react component:

```js
export const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await import('./Dashboard.css');
      console.log('foo');
    })();
  }, []);
```

I would have thought this css file would not get loaded until the code block has run but the style sheet is loaded when the app starts.

My `tsconfig.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "../../node_modules",
    "build",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `Dashboard` is not being constructed right away?  If you have, then the issue is probably related to a build step (maybe webpack).  Are you using TypeScript or plain JS?  If TypeScript, the issue is probably in your tsconfig.json (post that).

Comment: the console.log statement is not there until I navigate to that view

Comment: ah yes I am using typescript, I'll update the question

Comment: @user2740650 I've posted the tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

In your tsconfig, set module to"esnext".  It's critical to allow dynamic loading.